How can I put/call a .html file inside a React component?
I am trying to include a basic .html file to do some tests with my project, the problem is that when I include it and call the view which have to show it at the center of the page, what I see is the same page that I have but smaller.
This is the basic .html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
   <h1>My First Heading</h1>
   <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </body>
 </html>

This is my react Component
import React from 'react';

   function MapComponent() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Test</h1>
          <iframe src="./test.html" style={{ width: '600px', height: '600px' }}>. 
          </iframe>
         </div>
     );
 }

export default MapComponent;

And this is what browser shows:

Anyone knows what is happening?

In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is there indeed a request made for test.html?  If the server is returning the wrong page in response to that request then it sounds like the problem is server-side.

In the network tab I can see the request to the file and it has been successful

And what is the response to that request?  If the response is the page shown then the code shown is working as expected.

Response is Status 304 but, if I open that file, it shows me the page that I have, I do not understand this, if I have a .html file with two  why when I open the file that I have requested I see another page?

If the server is returning the wrong page in response to that request then it sounds like the problem is server-side.  The code shown is only making a request and displaying the result of that request, and it is doing that successfully.

But there is no server-side part, the .html file is on the folder

In your browser's debugging tools, when the <iframe> makes a request for test.html, what is the full and complete URL being requested?  If you aren't using a web server of any kind and are relying on file:// URLs then that's going to be very limiting, you'll definitely want to start using a web server for development.

Hey @Tomas, have you tried the solution described here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78438406/8997321

You don't need relative src. Use import instead:
import test from "test.html";

To display the content of the test.html file, either:

Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML: <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page }} />
Encode the content with encodeURIComponent, and combine it with iframe: <iframe src={"data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(page)} width={300} height={300} />

Side note: use dangerouslySetInnerHTML only if you have good control over the content, otherwise it will expose your users to cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

Let me test tomorrow morning this code and I tell you if it works, thanks a lot!

Hi again and sorry, I could not try it this morning, I am trying it now. This is a perfect solution, it works! Thanks a lot!
